# Sonar-runner - cannot find the sources for '#include <pthread.h>'

Tags: c, configuration, installation, sonarqube, coverity

I'm trying to run sonar-runner on a project of mine.

Relative to the root of the project directory, I have several subdirectories each which has its own subdirectories which contain the source code.

I followed the SonarQube and Sonar-runner documents and got the server and (embedded) database running fine. As a matter of fact, the runner can show me in the SonarQube web interface dashboard some analysis. However, the one I care about the most, "Issues", is missing and I suspect it's because the runner can't find *any* header files while it's executing.

All I see during sonar-runner execution is

```
cannot find the sources for '#include <pthread.h>'
cannot find the sources for '#include <time.h>'
```

and so on. It also can't include custom headers.

I'm running this with the Coverity and cxx community plugin if that makes a noticeable difference.

Note: I ran the example sets for both java and C and they run fine.

The commands are in my path so at the root of my project I run:

```
sonar-runner
```

Comment: Could you add the exact line you use to run SonarRunner?

Answer (score 1):

on your sonar-properties files set the sonar.cxx.includeDirectories to the folder that contains the header for example:

```
sonar.cxx.includeDirectories=c:\folderofheaders
```

see [wiki](https://github.com/SonarOpenCommunity/sonar-cxx/wiki/Supported-configuration-properties) although its not necessary to check because it says the same thing.